# How can I change my 12.04 login screen?

Tags: 12.04, login, screen

I want to change my ubuntu 12.04 login screen. I tried using ubuntu tweak and lightdm manager but none of them worked.After changing the image in tweak,I logged and changed the desktop image but nothing changed.While using lightdm manager too no changes were seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try your images in .png format. 
Or use simple light dm manager with .png format images

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/simple-lightdm-manager.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ubuntu tweak. Go to tweaks>Login Settings. You need to unlock the button at the top right of the window. Then click on the log in screen image. You will be directed to choose a .png file to be used as log in screen.